# share a dojo/store between different widgets

Tags: dojo, store

Is there a pattern to share a single dojo/store between multiple widgets?

I have multiple widgets on the same page that use the same dojo/store, and I don't want to duplicate it, so I don't need to make the same REST calls twice.

Comment: Have you tried making the store global and passing as argument to different widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a separate module where you store state and operations for your `dojo/store`.
The module will contains an "API' that your widgets can access.

Below a very simple example using the *single tone pattern*.

```
define([], function () {
   'use strict';

    var _instance;
    function _StoreManager() {
    }
    _StoreManager.prototype = {
        _privateMember: null,
        getDataFromApi: function () { 
            //...
        },
        saveDataToApi: function (data) {
            //...
        },
    };
    return function _getSingleton() {
        // summary:
        //      Gets singleton object.
        return (_instance = (_instance || new _StoreManager()));
    };
});
```

Require the module and use it.

```
require(['_StoreManager'],function(_StoreManager){
   _StoreManager.saveDataToApi({});
});
```